# mysql cant log in as a regular user using root, same as phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, authentication, phpmyadmin, installation, linux-mint

I installedd LLMP on default, fresh Linux Mint 18 Mate install. Everything is updated and pretty fresh. Then the strange problem occured with logging into the database.
My exact steps:
1. Installed lighttpd. It crashed until I installed also gamin package, then it works.

2. Installed php7 with php-mysql
3. Installed mariadb-server
4. Run mysql_secure_install, defined new root password, answered all Y for deleting test db, disabling anonymous accounts and disallowing root login from tcp, etc. Everything was suggested as a valid, default answer.
5. Installed phpmyadmin, this fails on post-install, but running apt-get install -f repaired it and finished install correctly.

WTF1: Now, as root user I can login without password to mysql in the console.

WTF2: I can't login to mysql as a regular user, even when I give good password.  It says "ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'"

WTF3: I can't also login to database using phpmyadmin, using root account and proper password, when run on my localhost workstation via lighttpd.

What the heck is going on? My expectation was it should work out of the box, allowing me to login ONLY with root password either on CLI or via phpmyadmin. What is wrong?

Comment: OK, some solutions I tried did not work:
1. Replacing localhost with 127.0.0.1 in configuration
2. Replacing mysqli to mysql in config file of phpmyadmin

What's worked: https://askubuntu.com/questions/763336/cannot-enter-phpmyadmin-as-root-mysql-5-7

So, creation of another privileged user was ENOUGH to gain admin acces, because root is blacklisted for some stupid reason.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this and the answer is in the comment to the question.